# How to give a ranking to rows based on multiple criteria against weighted factors?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, ranking-functions

I'm setting up an excel file that lets you input values, and then it will provide a ranking of 1 to 5 on each value, and then compare all values based on a set of weighted values.

It is a business problem that I'm struggling with because I somehow need to devise a ranking system that needs to take into account all factors to decide which of the options I want to do is the best one.

However, some of the factors require a different arrangement of the IF function. Because for some of the column, the higher the value = the lower the ranking and vice versa.

I have already set the criteria for rankings 1 to 5 of each factor.

Example: the higher the number of prospects, the higher the ranking. the higher the cost per conversion, the lower the ranking. And so on. Below is an example of the code that I have made: It differs for each column (I will provide a link to the file)

```
=IF(D7<1," ",IF(D7<=500,"1",IF(D7<=2500,"2",IF(D7<=3750,"3",IF(D7<=5000,"4",IF(D7>5000,"5"))))))

=IF(E7<1," ",IF(E7<=250,"1",IF(E7<=499,"2",IF(E7<=999,"3",IF(E7<=2500,"4",IF(E7>2500,"5"))))))

=IF(F7>7,"1",IF(F7>5,"2",IF(F7>3,"3",IF(F7>1,"4",IF(F7=1,"5",IF(F7<1," "))))))

=IF(G7>29,"1",IF(G7>19,"2",IF(G7>9,"3",IF(G7>4,"4",IF(G7>0.1,"5",IF(G7=0," "))))))

=IF(H7<1," ",IF(H7<=500000,"1",IF(H7<=1200000,"2",IF(H7<=2500000,"3",IF(H7<=4000000,"4",IF(H7>4000000,"5"))))))
```

So now we have a new table which includes all the rankings 1 to 5. But, I have not (or will have to) somehow put the weighted factors into the equation to consider the weights (as this will really affect the final ranking results).

This is the part that I struggle the most with, I could not find a function that somehow factors in the weighted values in order to give an overall value.

Thank you in advance for anyone who is able to help me with this.

[image: This is how it looks like now]

Comment: @player0 here you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tr8HaXxiouE2AZWhdMLOvfXkTqqG1wJqdYY9U4b2Sco/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes and no... So for the ruleset in L12:L16, I meant as a score, not a ranking. A score between 1 to 5. So a 5 would actually be a good one (therefore green).

Answer (score 0):

for rank only you can use in **L1** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(RANK(D5:D9, D5:D9, 1))
```

based on **D11:H18** rules it will look like:

[image: 0]

---

then to account for weight and rules in **L12:L16** you will get score per column like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(RANK(D5:D9,D5:D9,1)*L3*
 IF(D5:D9< 1, ,
 IF(D5:D9<=500,  1,
 IF(D5:D9<=2500, 2,
 IF(D5:D9<=3750, 3,
 IF(D5:D9<=5000, 4,
 IF(D5:D9> 5000, 5)))))))
```

[image: 0]

---

and then by summing scores per row, you will get a master score which you can rank like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(RANK(R21:R25, R21:R25))
```

[image: 0]

---

## [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FMLrYofRvjtBrsXL7vWAkywRb9Xec3oU1ceU0L50km4/edit#gid=1072427934)

Comment: Thank you for your help, however I was not really clear on how I want the final result should look like.

Firstly, I would only want 1 final master ranking. The "Rankings (1-5)" column with all the colors shouldn't keep changing. Instead, what I meant for this table is a score from 1-5 which is based on the criteria i have made with the IF functions.

So for the final ranking, it will only take into account the results based on the IF function * weights.

Answer (score 0):

delete everything in **L5:S9** range

paste this in **L5** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({L3*
 IF(D5:D9< 1, ,
 IF(D5:D9<=500,  1,
 IF(D5:D9<=2500, 2,
 IF(D5:D9<=3750, 3,
 IF(D5:D9<=5000, 4,
 IF(D5:D9> 5000, 5)))))),
 M3*
 IF(E5:E9< 1, ,
 IF(E5:E9<=250,  1,
 IF(E5:E9<=499,  2,
 IF(E5:E9<=999,  3,
 IF(E5:E9<=2500, 4,
 IF(E5:E9> 2500, 5)))))), 
 N3*
 IF(F5:F9< 1, ,
 IF(F5:F9> 7, 1,
 IF(F5:F9> 5, 2,
 IF(F5:F9> 3, 3,
 IF(F5:F9> 1, 4,
 IF(F5:F9= 1, 5)))))),
 O3*
 IF(G5:G9= 0, ,
 IF(G5:G9> 29,  1,
 IF(G5:G9> 19,  2,
 IF(G5:G9> 9,   3,
 IF(G5:G9> 4,   4,
 IF(G5:G9> 0.1, 5)))))), 
 P3*
 IF(H5:H9< 1, ,
 IF(H5:H9<=500000,  1,
 IF(H5:H9<=1200000, 2,
 IF(H5:H9<=2500000, 3,
 IF(H5:H9<=4000000, 4,
 IF(H5:H9> 4000000, 5))))))})
```

---

paste this in **R5** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(L5:L9+M5:M9+N5:N9+O5:O9+P5:P9)
```

---

paste this in **S5** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(RANK(R5:R9, R5:R9))
```

[image: 0]

---

## [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FMLrYofRvjtBrsXL7vWAkywRb9Xec3oU1ceU0L50km4/edit#gid=414714506)

---

or alternative (if you don't want to alter **L5:P9** range):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({L3*
 IF(D5:D9< 1, ,
 IF(D5:D9<=500,  1,
 IF(D5:D9<=2500, 2,
 IF(D5:D9<=3750, 3,
 IF(D5:D9<=5000, 4,
 IF(D5:D9> 5000, 5))))))+
 M3*
 IF(E5:E9< 1, ,
 IF(E5:E9<=250,  1,
 IF(E5:E9<=499,  2,
 IF(E5:E9<=999,  3,
 IF(E5:E9<=2500, 4,
 IF(E5:E9> 2500, 5))))))+ 
 N3*
 IF(F5:F9< 1, ,
 IF(F5:F9> 7, 1,
 IF(F5:F9> 5, 2,
 IF(F5:F9> 3, 3,
 IF(F5:F9> 1, 4,
 IF(F5:F9= 1, 5))))))+
 O3*
 IF(G5:G9= 0, ,
 IF(G5:G9> 29,  1,
 IF(G5:G9> 19,  2,
 IF(G5:G9> 9,   3,
 IF(G5:G9> 4,   4,
 IF(G5:G9> 0.1, 5))))))+ 
 P3*
 IF(H5:H9< 1, ,
 IF(H5:H9<=500000,  1,
 IF(H5:H9<=1200000, 2,
 IF(H5:H9<=2500000, 3,
 IF(H5:H9<=4000000, 4,
 IF(H5:H9> 4000000, 5))))))})
```

[image: 0]